# Haskell Morse Code Exercise - how to add "gaps" between list items

Tags: list, haskell, types, syntax, morse-code

I am currently working on a Morse code encoder in Haskell. This is my first time working in Haskell and I'm finding it difficult to think in a "functional" way. So far I have come up with this:

```
module Formative1
    (encode, decode, toTree, toTable)
where

import safe Lib

encode :: String -> [MorseUnit]
encode str = codeText(words str)

codeWord :: String -> [MorseUnit]
codeWord word = map codeSymbol word

codeText :: [String] -> [MorseUnit]
codeText list = map codeWord list
```

To explain my code:
`encode` is the main function. It uses `words` to break down sentences into a list of words. `codeText` is used to apply the function `codeWord` over each word in the list. `codeWord` then `maps` over each character in each word and finds the `MorseUnit` using `codeSymbol`.

I have two issues with this solution:

Issue 1: I get an error every time I run it due to `[MorseUnit]` not matching `[[MorseUnit]]`, I believe this is due to me using `map` twice so it's made a list within a list. But I can't think of another solution without using `map`.

Issue2: The rules of Morse Code state, after each letter, there should be a "shortGap", and after each word, there should be a "mediumGap". I have no idea how to insert either string inbetween each element of the list (I would insert shortGap between every element in `map codeSymbol word` so the shortGaps are between each letter, and I would insert mediumGap between every element in `map codeWord list` so the mediumGaps are between each word). I also don't understand at what point would I add the gaps because I don't want to accidentally apply `codeSymbol` to any of the gaps and replace them.

Any solutions would be helpful! Thank you.

Comment: For inserting gaps, you probably want [`intersperse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersperse). For the type error, you probably just want to use a `concat` to flatten your list in place. Without seeing more datatypes, that's the best I can help with!

Comment: @jkeuhlen 
 
Thanks for the reply. I have been able to get rid of the [[MorseUnit]] issue by using concat. However, whereever I insert "intersperse", I get an issue with matching types and scopes. Here's my code: encode :: String -> [MorseUnit] encode str = codeText (words str) codeWord :: String -> [MorseUnit] codeWord word = intersperse("shortGap" (concat(map codeSymbol word))) codeText :: [String] -> [MorseUnit] codeText list = intersperse("mediumGap" (concat(map codeWord list)))

Answer (score 1):

### Issue 1

You are exactly correct that the error is due to two maps. But you can also see it from the type signatures:

```
codeText list = map codeWord list (where list :: [String])
codeWord :: String -> [MorseUnit]
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

If you replace `(a -> b)` with `(String -> [MorseUnit])`, then `[a]` becomes `[String]`, and `[b]` becomes `[[MorseUnit]]`.

As in mathematics there are many ways to do it. Obviously you could just [`concat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat) the resulting list. Notice the straightforward `[[a]] -> [a]` signature.

Notice that immediately after that there is [`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap). You could use it in place of `map`, and it would flatten the result for you.

To further confuse you, in case you find your parameter appearing last in both the declaration and the definition, you could omit it:

```
codeText = concatMap codeWord
```

I recommend you use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[a]->[a]) to search for the function signature you want.

### Issue 2

First, since you need to distinguish between word and symbols, it seems to me you might not need to flatten the list so early. I am not familiar with Morse code so I don't fully understand what you want to do there. It would be much more clear if you could express your concept in types and signatures. My suggestion is to look at `intersperse :: a -> [a] -> [a]` or `intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]` to insert your gaps. They need to be imported with `import Data.List`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have been able to get rid of the [[MorseUnit]] issue by using concat (I will look into function calls later, but my deadline means I have to use the quickest solution). However, whereever I insert "intersperse", I get an issue with matching types and scopes. If I do Here's my code:   encode :: String -> [MorseUnit]
encode str = codeText (words str)

codeWord :: String -> [MorseUnit]
codeWord word = intersperse("shortGap" (concat(map codeSymbol word)))

codeText :: [String] -> [MorseUnit]
codeText list = intersperse("mediumGap" (concat(map codeWord list)))

Comment: You may not need `concat` in `codeWord`. `String` equals `[Char]` in Haskell so you need to use `intercalate` on `String`.

Comment: When I use "intercalate", I get a "variable not in scope" error

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check. Add `import Data.List` to import it.

Comment: That worked thank you! The only issue left is where to place "intersperse". I get an error  about the match type regardless of whether I do it before or after concat. In this example I've done it after concat:    codeWord :: String -> [MorseUnit]
codeWord word = intersperse("shortGap" (intercalate(map codeSymbol word)))

codeText :: [String] -> [MorseUnit]
codeText list = intersperse("mediumGap" (concat(map codeWord list)))

Comment: Several issues: 1) unlike other lang Haskell don't use `()` to apply functions. So use `intersperse shortGap list` no paren; 2) `intersperse` and `intercalate` only works on single-type list. You can't put a `String` in a `[MorseUnit]`. You need to define it as a variant of `MorseUnit`: `data MorseUnit = String | ShortGap` and use the type instead of the string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156296/discussion-between-fridsun-and-assassinsweed1).